# How to (elegantly) iterate two lists at once?

Tags: clojure

I want to find better looking alternative to this code:

```
(def x (range 1 10))
(def y '(0 4 3 5 1 2 7 3 11))
(for [i (range 0 (count y))] [(nth x i) (nth y i)])
```

If I already have the result of previous I can simply

```
(def z (for [i (range 0 (count y))] [(nth x i) (nth y i)]))
(for [[x y] z] [x y])
```

Can you find some better looking alternative?

Example is made to be short and easilly to read. If you modify it to do something more complicated the first example can stop being readable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
(map vector x y)
```

Comment: If y is longer than x then you'd have to pad x with nils to get the same behavior as OP's code. But since the example has x and y same length this will work.

Comment: Scratch that - OP's code will throw exception if y is longer. So this is a safer alternative anyways.